# python GPIO inputs, checking the time for different results

Tags: python, input, raspberry-pi, gpio

Thank you for reading this and offering your time to help.

I am using a raspberry pi B 2 + and python to trial this.

I am trying to check the time that my input GPIO pin is set to logic high, as the device I am using will set logic high for set times to represent different conditions. Such as:

- 1mS Pulse = open
- 3mS Pulse = closed
- 5mS Pulse = fault

I need to read these as different conditions so I can set if statements.

Such as if the input is a 1ms pulse I need to set one of my output pins to logic high, this will need to be different to a 2ms pulse or a 5ms pulse.

Many thanks
Will

Answer (score 0):

I would comment this answer since i am not sure if it will help you, but i can't.
Couldn't you use the time.time() function?

Make a while loop that checks the GPIO's input condition.

```
while GPIO.input(pin_number)==0:
  pulse_start = time.time()
while GPIO.input(pin_number)==1:
  pulse_end = time.time()


pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start
```

Hope this is what you were looking for. Let me know if this helped or not. (Also to use time.time() you must import time.

Comment: sorry about the delay, I have tried using this so thank you for the help, however, it never sees the end of the pulse. I added text to tell me when the while loop ran, open for the pulse start and closed for pulse end, and it constantly printed open never exiting the loop.